# SAML Redirect sign or verify failing to produce correct signature

Tags: c#, saml-2.0

I am using the following code to successfully produce a signature for my SAML. I have the POST sorted using XML sign, however REDIRECT is completely different. I am unable to produce the same signature as https://www.samltool.com/sign_logout_req.php and when I try and validate a genuine signature it is failing.

I took it back to basics and tried to see if I could sign it in the same manner and I cannot which suggests something is wrong with the way I am forming the data.

The following details (into samltool.com):

```
<saml:LogoutRequest ID="_02380F63816E0E92D6537758C37FE05F" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-06-21T15:34:59.911Z" Destination="https://myteststs.net/appname/auth/" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://w.sp-app.com</saml:Issuer><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">1869374313</saml:NameID></saml:LogoutRequest>
```

Private key (testcert)

```
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
```

x.509

```
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
```

RelayState:

```
RELAYTEST
```

SigAlg:

```
#rsa-sha1
```

So... using the ssotool it produces the signature :

> IG4VDmVwQRZWa75NmwjtqKlPVdCx6tm73gL7j3xvrqXsfirunUtr626SBmQJ4mke77bYzXg8D1hAy5EREOhz2QH23j47XexqbVSNTtAkZV7KP1/lO8K01tiQr8SGJqzdFor/FZZscIDFlw3cBLXhGSwWK9i0qO/e55qkgxJS9OA=

However.. using the code below (and many.. many.. variations) I cannot get it to produce that same signature. Please note the samlrequest is base64encoded with compression as recommended (but you can deflate it to the same output). I have followed this specification too (3.4.4.1):https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf

```
static byte[] Sign(string data, string certSubject)
    {

        // Access Personal (MY) certificate store of current user
        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);


        // Find the certificate we’ll use to sign
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in my.Certificates)
        {
            if (cert.Subject.Contains(certSubject))
            {
                // Get its associated CSP and private key
                csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

            }
        }

        if (csp == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No valid cert was found");
        }

        string certAlgorithm = csp.SignatureAlgorithm;


        // Hash the data
        SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();

        byte[] dataRaw = encoding.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(dataRaw);


        // Sign the hash
        return csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
    }

    static bool Verify(string text, byte[] signature, string certPublic)
    {

        // Load the certificate we’ll use to verify the signature from a file
        X509Certificate2 appSigningX509Certificate = null;
        var appSigningCertificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certPublic);
        appSigningX509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(appSigningCertificateBytes);

        // Get its associated CSP and public key
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)appSigningX509Certificate.PublicKey.Key;


        // Hash the data
        SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();

        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);


        // Verify the signature with the hash
        return csp.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature);
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Usage sample
        try
        {

            string cert = "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";

            string samlRequestCompressed = "nZFPS8QwEMW/Ssl906TZ/gttQWwLhdWDyh68SKjBLbRJ7ExQv71traA38TiPee/9hilATaM82Rfr8U6/eg0YdHVJnlgkMtYmIuNJw5o8qpNYpGmcXYu0bVjckuCsZxisKUlEGQk6AK87A6gMLhLj6YElh4g/8FiKo4xzmnP+SIJ6aRiMws15QXQgwxC1Uab/MGrSdFBTP1r/TI3GUDm3iqE7KI+XkATv02hArtAl8bORVsEAct0Bib28v7o5yYVHutmi7e1IqmK7cMOb/2xXAHpeGUn1zfhGYaFwjvZ2KsIfoXvD7RLS1f9p4FmSi/QouNhzv6Kqffr1nOoT";
            string relaystate = "RELAYTEST";
            string algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

            string data = String.Empty;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(relaystate))
            {
                data = String.Format("SAMLRequest={0}&SigAlg={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(samlRequestCompressed), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(algorithm));
            }
            else
            {
                data = String.Format("SAMLRequest={0}&RelayState={1}&SigAlg={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(samlRequestCompressed,Encoding.UTF8), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(relaystate,Encoding.UTF8), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(algorithm,Encoding.UTF8));
            }

            // Sign text
            byte[] signature = Sign(data, "{2F879585-7C54-450D-88FB-A3F713646EC6}");

            string b64encodedSig = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
            string expectedSig = "IG4VDmVwQRZWa75NmwjtqKlPVdCx6tm73gL7j3xvrqXsfirunUtr626SBmQJ4mke77bYzXg8D1hAy5EREOhz2QH23j47XexqbVSNTtAkZV7KP1/lO8K01tiQr8SGJqzdFor/FZZscIDFlw3cBLXhGSwWK9i0qO/e55qkgxJS9OA=";

            if (b64encodedSig != expectedSig)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not what i expected");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            // Verify signature. Testcert.cer corresponds to “cn=my cert subject”
            if (Verify(data, signature, cert))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Signature verified");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Signature not valid!");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " +ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I cannot seem to understand how to produce the sign data in the same way. I have also confirmed the locally installed certificate is exactly the same as the one above.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this now.

The solution was that the HttpUtility.URLEncode is not encoding it to the same standard as the SAML standards (or OneLogin). I figured it out by looking at the compressed data and that matched but the URL Encoded one different.

The answer was to use Uri.EscapeString.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue and signature verification getting failed at IDP side. Can you please post the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the same signature as OneLogin, you have to use the same URL encoding as them. Other URL encodings will result in different signatures, but they are perfectly valid as well.

[See the SAML specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf) (3.4.4.1):

> Further, note that URL-encoding is not canonical; that is, there are multiple legal encodings for a given value. The relying party MUST therefore perform the verification step using the original URL-encoded values it received on the query string. It is not sufficient to re-encode the parameters after they have been processed by software because the resulting encoding may not match the signer's encoding.

As noted in [another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728112/12534), OneLogin seems to use URL encoding matching `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode()` in .NET -- but note also that they *do not* URL encode the base64-encoded signature itself, even though it can contain characters such as [+/=]. The SAML specification is not very clear, but seems to suggest that this is wrong,

> Note that some characters in the base64-encoded signature value may themselves require URL-encoding before being added.

This last bit is crucial to be able to validate your signature with their tools.

Comment: That is one of the few unfortunate passages in the spec, yes. This is why our advice is always this - test with a real IdP.