# C# - How to Sign SAML Request using HTTPRedirect Binding

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, http-redirect, signing

We have developed web site in Angular 5 using .Net Web API and SQL Server. The website has been deployed on Azure. Website has been successfully integrated with SSO (Ping Federator) using SAML 2.0.

Now we have a requirement to Sign SAML request. We have private and public key and getting “Invalid Signature” error at IDP side while sending signed SAML request. Below is sample SAML request.

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest 
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    ID="_6727de62-72e3-48fd-836a-04332e7b2453" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2018-08-27T05:07:04Z" 
    Destination="https://sso/SSO.saml2" 
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://mysite/login" 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer>http://issuersite.com</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy 
        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" 
        AllowCreate="true" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

The same has been constructed using following.

```
url = ssourl + “?” + "SAMLRequest=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request) + "&Signature=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_signature);
```

Below is the signed SAML request.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://mysite/login " ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" IssueInstant="2018-08-07T07:40:36Z" Version="2.0" ID="_b8e67b27-cdd0-41ad-afe3-d98074813ec9"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> http://issuersite.com </saml:Issuer><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI="#_b8e67b27-cdd0-41ad-afe3-d98074813ec9"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>NhZ1uC0aHuTf3/u6jmAShInBWtE=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>YslaCvEyqd8XTnXEElDNawX399eZ61NWrE4ue/PVBmUoycIQ5kkCixnZSUEShJKL8UXuAOgIG/wW7jWZKpVY4ouIPafRDjQBVk/M7kAoMVdSVbAdZcqQLO0yGZLOyhOzyCF/O71wnxHPHIIKyf47vBt6GCyEB3MKioNXnU8fx8htig/AqKh6Ff6lku9zNpl88MugP5S9ZDzzBpmspLPP0cuO2dfiKsmYfMxfUrOcy2+FT33eBsnXDivD1he4Ts7LKW6HZJbY3LsqTc0U3qcjgJs9lmwcbqz27okojl6dz17ZAR42NNveaSRV8t09aPVuf+VVtWbEXHsqSPTrV2J9lQ==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature><samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"/></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

**request is deflated using memory stream and base64 encoded.
_ signature is the signed xml and base64 encoded.**

*We are able to successfully sign XML document but getting error while signing SAML request.*

Tried following options but none of them working. Please share any inputs to fix this issue. Let me know if any other details are required on this.

[SAML Redirect sign or verify failing to produce correct signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701958/saml-redirect-sign-or-verify-failing-to-produce-correct-signature)

[HTTP-Redirect Binding SAML Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388926/http-redirect-binding-saml-request/33919437)

Comment: @praveen Kumar I am having the same issue, please help me with the solution if you have resolved the issue.

Comment: Pls refer to this link. I was able to resolve the issue. https://github.com/elerch/SAML2/tree/master/src/SAML2.Core